# CSS inline and embedded stylesheets

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm enrolled in a HTML-CSS course and I'm on one of the final assignments but I cant solve it tried for a whole day now. And the validator at wc3 says not much is wrong with my code. Problem first of all is the text does not format to Bold and Italic like I've written in the class and the third is no box is displaying with no borders.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <STYLE TYPE="text/css" MEDIA=screen>
      p#speciell {
        font-style: italic;
      }

      p#speciell2 {
        font-weight : bold;
      }

      #DatorID {
        font-family : Helvetica, italic, underline;
        font-size : 25px;
        background : #ffffff;
        color : maroon;
      }

      .block3 { 
        font-family: Times New Roman;
        font-size: 16px;
        background: #c9e9ff;
        border: 6px #a52a2a
        border-style: double;
        border-color: #a52a2a;
        Padding: 5px;
        color: navy;
        width; 70%;
      }
    </STYLE>
    <LINK REL=StyleSheet HREF="style.css" TYPE="text/css" MEDIA=screen />
  </head>
  <body>
    <p class ="#speciell"> Text </p>
    <p class ="#speciell2"> Text </p>
    <div class="block">
      Text I want in a box with the formats
    </div>
```

Comment: You have a rule for the class `block3` and your element has a class `block`. No match.

Comment: You have a rule for the IDs `speciell` and `speciell2`, and your elements have classes `#speciell` and `#speciell2`. No matches, and also you're using the `#` in the wrong way. It should be used to define a rule for some element ID. For classes, you should use `.`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few errors there.

- You have a rule for the class `block3` and your element has a class `block`. No match.
- You have a rule for the IDs `speciell` and `speciell2`, and your elements have classes `#speciell` and `#speciell2`. No matches, and also you're using the `#` in the wrong way. It should be used to define a rule for some element ID. For classes, you should use `.`.

Fixing these, you get:

```
<p class="speciell">Text</p> <!-- Removed the # from the class name -->
<p class="speciell2">Text</p> <!-- Removed the # from the class name -->
<div class="block">Text I want in a box with the formats</div>
```

And:

```
p.speciell { /* Replaced the # that defines an ID with a . that defines a class */
    font-style: italic;
}
p.speciell2 { /* Replaced the # that defines an ID with a . that defines a class */
    font-weight : bold;
}
#DatorID {
    font-family : Helvetica, italic, underline;
    font-size : 25px;
    background : #ffffff;
    color : maroon;
}
.block { /* Corrected the class name */
    font-family: Times New Roman;
    font-size: 16px;
    background: #c9e9ff;
    border: 6px #a52a2a;
    border-style: double;
    border-color: #a52a2a;
    Padding: 5px;
    color: navy;
    width:70%; /* Corrected a typo */
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jq7pU/2/)

Comment: In addition to changing those IDs to classes, I would avoid the the use of "block" as a class name; block is CSS display attribute and doesn't define the class well. It will work, but is confusing. In addition, I would change the class names to something more meaningful; remember in the professional world another developer may have to edit your code so keep it logical and simple.

Comment: +1 for adding good information.

Comment: I'd also remove any superfluous classes (i.e. #DatorID may be unnecessary). As an HTML/CSS instructor in the past, these little things are a nice touch in student work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It was quite simple things I've missed. Although I'm totally Noob to CSS and HTML. One more question how do I make the borders visible on the box?

Comment: It should be visible now. I've missed this bit (another typo) when posting the answer. It's updated.